# Acessando Webservices diferentes no Android

Tags: java, android, web-service

Eu tenho um app que estou desenvolvendo para a minha empresa, que a primeira parte, é fazer o login, passando pelos webservices, após o login, ele faz automáticamente mais uma conexão ao webservice que retorna para ele uma URL, que para cada cliente, terá uma das 2 URL existentes.

Por exemplo:

```
www.dominio.com/ws/mobile.asmx
www.dominio.com.br/ws/mobile.asmx
```

A diferença como podem ver, é o .br

O que acontece é o seguinte, qualquer outra função que eu criei neste app, estão funcionais.
Só que somente funciona no .COM, e não no .BR, os dois webservices são IDÊNTICOS, literalmente, só muda mesmo o .com e o .br
Por qual motivo eu posso não estar conseguindo acessar? Sempre dá erro 404 de página não encontrada no Logcat, mas o link e o ws realmente existem, testados e etc.
E não tem como o meu código estar errado, porque se funciona para um, o outro tem que obrigatoriamente funcionar igualmente..

Aonde eu posso estar errando?

Se precisarem de mais dados, me digam, pois não sei uma solução para isto..

Comment: Testando por outro cliente, sem ser no dispositivo, funciona?

Comment: funciona no Visual Studio, pelo próprio browser.. Tô sem respostas do que pode ser.. @Wakim

Comment: @Wakim, tem alguma sugestão para mim? Estou desesperado

Comment: Não faço muita idéia, talvez seja bom colocar o código que chama o Web Service e que define essas URL'S.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você recebe uma das duas URLs. Então, por que no ponto onde você recebe a URL você não faz algo desse tipo:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("sua url");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); // Vai imprimir a resposta como json.
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Dessa maneira, você vai executar qualquer URL passada. Verifique somente a necessidade de utilizar `HttpPost`.